# YQL cache busting

Tags: caching, yql

I'm using YQL to scrape some data from another site that updates daily, but regardless of my efforts, the returned data is at least a day old if not older. In other words, it is not the actual data on the website that I'm scraping. I assume it it being cached and from I read I need to use some kind of cache busting technique to force it to get new data. Here is the core of my calling code:

```
SomeClass.prototype.testfunc = function () {
    var _this = this;

    var site = "http://www.somesite.shtml";
    var xpath = '//table[@id="someId"]/tbody/tr';
    var yql = "https://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=" + encodeURIComponent("select * from html where url='" + site + "' and xpath='" + xpath + "'") + "&format=json&callback=?&rnd=2";

    $.ajax({
        url: yql, 
        dataType: 'json',
        cache: false,
        success: _this.testFunc
    });

SomeClass.prototype.testFunc = function (data) {
    if (data != undefined) {
        //handle returned data
    }
}
```

I have tried 2 different cache-busting techniques to get it to retrieve current data: 1) "cache: false" in the ajax call and 2) added the "&rnd=#" to the end of the yql string which I have manually changed to different numbers in testing to see if would make a difference.

I get the data, but unfortunately it is still day(s) old. It appears neither approach is working and I'm wondering what I can do to get fresh data.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add a query string in your `site` var to avoid cache, like this:

`var site = "http://www.somesite.shtml?t=<timestamp>";`